# Finding the value of an auto-increment field

Tags: python, mysql

I have a simple registration form which creates a new record in "Students" table:

```
cur = con.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO students (Name, Address, Major, Phone, Email, Password) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
args = [name, address, major,phone, email, password]

cur.execute(query, args)
con.commit()
```

The column Id is auto-incremented, so in order to get the last Id, I select Max

```
query = "SELECT MAX(Id) FROM students;"
cur.execute(query)
id = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

It works in my little homework-project, but how would it be done in a heavy-loaded project, where there is a possibility of something being created before the select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`lastrowid`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#lastrowid) attribute:

```
...
cur.execute(query, args)
id = cur.lastrowid
```

Comment: @Anarion, It (before/after) will not make difference if you use the same cursor object.

Comment: Thank you. It will get me an "internal" id from the database? No the value of the 'Id' column? (Forgive my naive questions)

Comment: hmm, works in terminal, does not work in pages... `message = str(cur.lastrowid)` message is = 0....

Comment: @Anarion, What pages? Web page? Could you post a separated question with the detail of the pages.

Comment: Ah, I need to do cur.lastrowid before commit. Commit turns it to 0.

Comment: @Anarion, It's strange. `cur.lastrowid()` give me correct id before/after the commit.

Comment: Must have been some kind of typo, since it started working both before and after commit. Thanks.